# AWS: Migrate go1.x runtime to al2 in order to deploy Lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lambda, make

I'm trying to migrate to the AL2 runtime from go1.x to deploy my Lambda functions but I'm having troubles with how to do so. I use the Serverless Framework for deployment in conjunction with make. Here is the Makefile that I currently use:

```
go_apps = bin/func1 bin/func2 bin/fun3

bin/% : functions/%.go functions/common.go
    env GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o $@ $< functions/common.go

build: $(go_apps)

clean:
    rm -rf ./bin

deploy:
    sls deploy --verbose

install: build deploy
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

---

Update:
[I found this article that should help with migration](https://blog.matthiasbruns.com/running-multiple-golang-aws-lambda-functions-on-arm64-with-serverlesscom)

I'll report back when I've implemented it and ensures it works as intended

---

Update 2:

I was able to use SAM local to test my functions in the new AL2 runtime successfully [with the help of this AWS sample AL2 implementation with Go](https://github.com/aws-samples/sessions-with-aws-sam/tree/master/go-al2). I moved my common.go file to a new repository and built a go module successfully with it (which was then imported to my functions). This is just a start as I have yet to deploy my functions via Serverless but this might be helpful to others in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you can in fact do a go build with two (or more) files and run/deploy it to an AL2 runtime. Be sure your second file (in my case, common.go) has the functions/structs publicly accessible. Also, make sure you update github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda to the latest version. And use this [github repo sample](https://github.com/matthiasbruns/golang-sls-provided.al2-arm64/tree/main) to help with your serverless template.

This is a sample of my Makefile that is used to deploy to AWS Lambda using the Serverless framework:

```
go_bootstrap = func1 func2 func3 \

build: 
    for n in $(go_bootstrap); \
    do \
        echo "$$n"; \
        env GOOS=linux go build -o ./build/"$$n"/bootstrap functions/common.go functions/"$$n".go; \
        zip -j ./build/zip/"$$n".zip ./build/"$$n"/bootstrap; \
    done

deploy:
    sls deploy --verbose

install: build deploy
```